# How can I include a revision of a file in a Change Package after it was checked in

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

This happens occasionally in some projects I'm involved in that are using MKS as version control tool. A file is checked-out, modified and then checked-in but it was forgotten to be included in the related Change Package.

Is there a way to achieve this after the fact?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the one who checks-in the file permitted to NOT use a CP?

Answer (score 0):

Delete revision (yes, the command exists), and then check in again, this time tied to the CP. Make sure you preserve the working file in the meantime.

If you've new revisions on top of it, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what SzG said really exists ( if so, I'd like to know too :) )
Once any operation is done without a CP, that operation can't be associated to a CP.

A solution for the future would be, to make using the CP mandatory in the project setup.